# Проверьте мой unit-тест

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Код который тестирую:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace kinoshka
{
    public partial class AuthForm : Form
    {
        public AuthForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "123")
            {
                AdminForm adminForm = new AdminForm(this);
                adminForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

        public bool IsText(string password)
        {
            if (password == "")
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }



    }
}
```

Сам тест:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using kinoshka;

namespace kinoshka_test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            AuthForm test1 = new AuthForm();
            string pass = "";
            bool password = test1.IsText(pass);
            Assert.IsFalse(password);
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. помогите сделать... прощу

Comment: И какой функционал Вы хотите протестировать? (ЗЫ. зачем заводить новый аккаунт и задавать один и тот же вопрос 10 раз?)

Comment: в юнит тестах не надо тестировать интерфейс слой. Нужны тесты логики программы. Вам надо почитать по тестирование более детально